# How to bind windows user name to a text field and send to the SQL table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

### My "add new" view has this code to enter user details.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right;">
     <p><b>User attended</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Usr_atnd, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Usr_atnd, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

---

My windows user name is already displayed in the navbar. I want to add windows user name into this field and once the submit button is pressed, it should go to the DB table.
Could you please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: How is it displayed in the navbar?

Comment: Hi, it displayed like this(_layout page).  <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>

Comment: You can populate the model property from `User.Identity.Name` in controller code. and then shod it in the View... did you try that?

Comment: Thanks friend. It worked. I added it to my controller as you said. Boom, it worked. Thank you. :D